# All adjacency matrices of size n

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorics

What would be a concise way to get all adjacency matrices of size $n$, e.g. for $n=2$, these $(2^2)^2$ matrices:

```
{{0,0},
 {0,0}}

{{1,0},
 {0,0}}

{{0,1},
 {0,0}}

{{0,0},
 {1,0}}

{{0,0},
 {0,1}}

{{1,1},
 {0,0}}

{{1,0},
 {1,0}}

{{1,0},
 {0,1}}

{{0,1},
 {1,0}}

{{0,1},
 {0,1}}

{{0,0},
 {1,1}}

{{1,1},
 {1,0}}

{{1,1},
 {0,1}}

{{0,1},
 {1,1}}

{{1,0},
 {1,1}}

{{1,1},
 {1,1}}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html)

```
Tuples[{0, 1}, {2, 2}]

TeXForm @ Grid[Partition[MatrixForm /@ %, 8]]
```

> $\small\begin{array}{cccccccc}
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  0 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  0 & 0 \\
>  1 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  0 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  0 & 1 \\
>  0 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  0 & 1 \\
>  1 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  0 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 0 \\
>  1 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 1 \\
>  0 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \end{array}$

```
Grid[Partition[#, 4], Dividers -> All] & @
 (Labeled[AdjacencyGraph[#, DirectedEdges -> True, 
      VertexLabels -> "Name", ImageSize -> {120, 60}, 
      VertexSize -> Tiny, VertexCoordinates -> {{1/3, 0}, {2/3, 0}}], 
     Pane[MatrixForm[#], ImageMargins -> 10], Top] & /@ Tuples[{0, 1}, {2, 2}], 4])
```

[image]

#### [`IntegerDigits`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerDigits.html?q=IntegerDigits)

You can use `PadLeft` with `IntegerDigits` and `Partition` the results as follows:

```
n = 2;
Partition[#, n] & /@ PadLeft[IntegerDigits[Range[0, 2^( n^2) - 1], 2]]
% == Tuples[{0, 1}, {n, n}]
```

> True

Comment: definitely more concise and efficient :)

Answer (score 0):

```
connections = Subsets[Table[i, {i, 4}]];
MatrixForm /@ Table[ Partition[Table[If[MemberQ[c, i], 1, 0], {i, 4}], {2}], {c, connections}]
```

[image]

replace 4 with $n$ and $2$ with $\sqrt{n}$